# Integral test for convergence.The problem point in the denominator

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2 \cot{\left (x \right )} + 1}{2 \sin{\left (x \right )} + \cos{\left (x \right )}}\, dx$$

How to solve this problem? What are the main steps in solving this ? 
I understand that this integral should be wrtitten as a summ of integrals but I can't find the problem point.Is it this :

```
                           2*sin(x)+cos(x)=0

                           cos(x)/2sin(x)=-1

                             ctg(x)=-2
                             x=arcctg(-2)
```

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do in the grey box. $2\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ is clearly positive over $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Comment: The actual issue is that $2\cot(x)$ is not integrable in a right neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio,so what am I supposed to do ?

Comment: State that the integral is blatantly divergent, I guess.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio,how did you get it ?

Comment: I have already told you. $\cot(x)$ is not integrable in a right neighbourhood of the origin, it behaves like $\frac{1}{x}$.